# I'm getting an error: undefined reference to yyparse()

Tags: windows, flex-lexer, lex

I've run the following code in flex and got yyparse() error, The target output I'm hoping to get is :

```
P
font-size: 8px
font-family: arial
color: red
TD
background-color: yellow
border: 1px solid black
```

Here is my program:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include"yousuf.h"
int yylineno;
%}
%%
"<"[^>]*>           ;
[P]             {printf("P\n",yytext);}
"font-size: 8 px"       {printf("font-size: 8 px\n"); return FONTSIZE;}
"font-family: arial"        {printf("font-family: arial\n"); return FONTFAMILY;}
"color: red"            {printf("color: red\n"); return COLOR;}
[TD]                {printf("TD\n",yytext);}
"background-color: yellow"  {printf("background-color: yellow\n"); return BACKGROUNDCOLOR;}
"border: 1px solid black"   {printf("border: 1px solid black"); return BORDER;}
[ \t\n]             ;
.               ;   
%%
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
char string[]= "<style>P{font-size: 8px; font-family: arial; color: red;}TD{background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black;}</style>";
YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer= yy_scan_string(string);
yyparse();
yy_delete_buffer(buffer);
return 0;
}
int yywrap(void)
{
return 0; 
}
```

Also, is there any other way to feed input to flex other than `fopen("filename.txt","r")`; because it doesn't seem to read the file and take it as input.

Answer (score 1):

The function defined by (f)lex is called `yylex`. `yyparse` is generated by bison/yacc, which you do not appear to be using.

Flex takes its input from `yyin`, declared as:

```
extern FILE* yyin;
```

So it's not sufficient to just call `fopen`; you need to assign the return value to `yyin`. You should also make sure that the `fopen` call succeeded:

```
yyin = fopen("filename.txt","r");
if (yyin == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not open 'filename.txt': %s\n", strerror(errno));
  exit(1);
}
```

By the way, `[TD]` recognises either a `T` or a `D`. So with input `TD`, your rule will print `TD` twice.

Comment: Thanks @rici...but the program doesn't seem to run, it opens up my Documents folder when I run it...

Comment: @zack: i have no idea how that could happen since I'm not a Windows user, but it probably has something to do with your IDE.

Comment: Finally, got rid of the problem but now, when I run it, it  asks me for input rather than reading from the file...

Comment: @zack: the snippet in the answer should work just fine. Since I can't see the code you are trying, I cannot make any useful suggestion.

Comment: I used this: int main() 
{
extern FILE *yyin;
yyin = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
yylex();
return 0;
}   Also now the program works fine if i give the input myself,but  the return function doesn't work,,is there a way to include the print and return function for the same rule.

Comment: @Zack, as I said in the answer "You should also make sure that the fopen call succeeded:". If you don't check this and the fopen fails, then `yyin` will be set to NULL and the lexer will use standard input as a fallback. **ALWAYS** check the return value from library functions. They all tell you if they fail, and you can usually get a nice error message by using `perror`.

Comment: As far as the issue with `return` goes, if you put `return` into a scanner action, then `yylex` will return when the pattern is recognised. That's what `return` means. So if you are expecting `yylex` to return after every token, then you should call it in a loop. If you just call it once, it will stop after the first token with a return in its action. I don't know if that's the actual problem you are having, but it seems likely. You'd do well to read the flex manual, especially the code samples.